# How to send email to user after payment is done with paypal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, ruby-on-rails-3.2, paypal-sandbox

I want to sent email to user after transcation done. now paypal is working fine for me, but user is not getting mail notification after transcation done? how to get email notification for user .

Here is my code
This is my controller code

This is my paypal function

```
def pay
    if @order.update order_params
       @order.update_attributes(:invoice_id => rand.to_s[2..11])
      if current_user.billing_address.blank?
        current_user.create_billing_address(@order.billing_address.dup.attributes)
      end
      if current_user.shipping_address.blank?
        current_user.create_shipping_address(@order.shipping_address.dup.attributes)
      end
      # @cart.calculate_shipping
      if @order.total == 0
        return redirect_to checkout_thank_you_path
      end
      # if !params['payment'].present?
      #   return redirect_to :back, notice: 'Select Payment Gateway!'
      # end
      # if params['payment']=='paypal'
        @order.order_statuses.create(status_type: 1)
        item_details=[]
        @order.line_items.each do |item|
          item_details << {:name => item.title, :quantity => item.quantity, :amount => item.amount.fractional}
        end
        logger.info item_details.inspect
        response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(@cart.total.fractional,
                                                  :ip => request.remote_ip,
                                                  :currency =>"USD",
                                                  :items => item_details,
                                                  :order_id => @order.invoice_id,
                                                  :return_url => checkout_thank_you_url,
                                                  :cancel_return_url => cart_url
        )
        return redirect_to EXPRESS_GATEWAY.redirect_url_for(response.token)
      # else
      #   return redirect_to 'https://www.payumoney.com/'
      # end
    else
      flash[:alert] = 'Billing and shipping address fields are required!'
      render :addresses
    end
end
```

This is my thank function for paypal

```
  def thank_you
    @order = Order.find(session[:order_id])
    details = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.details_for(params[:token])
    response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.purchase(@cart.total.fractional, {
        ip: request.remote_ip,
        token: params[:token],
        payer_id: details.payer_id,
        items: @order.line_items.map{|l| {name: l.title, quantity: l.quantity, amount: l.amount.fractional}}
    })
    if response.success?
      # logger.info payment_params.inspect
      payment_params = {gateway: 'PayPal Express Checkout', transaction_id: response.params['token'], ip: request.remote_ip, amount: response.params['gross_amount']}
      @cart.order.created_at = DateTime.now
      @cart.order.status = 'Paid'
      @cart.order.save
      session.delete :order_id
      # OrderMailer.order_confirmation(@order).deliver
      # OrderMailer.admin_receipt(@order).deliver
    else
      redirect_to :cart_checkout, alert: 'Something went wrong. Please try again. If the problem persists, please contact us.'
    end
      @cart = Cart.new current_or_null_user.id, session[:order_id], session[:currency] # Start a new cart
  end
```

Any help is appreciatable

Comment: If any help is appreceated, I would advise moving some of that stuff to the model using Model Validations... The mail sending function could be an after_save callback in your Order Model. Also, you could generalize the paypal stuff in a PORO class, this way you could re-use it at another place in your code and makes testing easier. Also saves you a lot of headache when you decide to switch from PayPal to another payment provider. (I doubt the last part, since after code update it looks like you are using something like that already)

Comment: i alraedy done OrderMailer actionMailer. but here from @orders i am not getting email parameter